# Deserialize PHP Serialized Objects in Java(Spring Boot)

Tags: java, serialization

I am using Spring Boot.
In my project I want to deserialize some objects which are serialized in php and this serialized string is stored in redis.

Now I have fetched the serialized string in java and I am trying to re-convert it into Object.

What is the best way?

Also I have tried this

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.xk72</groupId>
            <artifactId>pherialize</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: stdClass objects only supported. `MyCustomObject' received.
```

My Code is :

```
    MixedArray list = Pherialize.unserialize(cacheObject.get("cacheKey").toString()).toArray();
```